# Unique rows based on two logical conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, tidyverse

I want my dataframe to return unique rows based on two logical conditions (OR not AND).

But when I ran this, **`df %>% group_by(sex) %>% distinct(state, education) %>% summarise(n=n())`** I got deduplicated rows based on the two conditions joined by AND not OR.

Is there a way to get something like this **`df %>% group_by(sex) %>% distinct(state | education) %>% summarise(n=n())`** so that the deduplicated rows will be joined by OR not AND?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a small example and your expected output?
I don't really understand what you are trying to do?
Assume that `state = c('A', 'B', 'A')`and `education = c('X', 'Y', 'Y')`, what would be the expected output?

Comment: Thank you. Based on your example, I expect the output to be ```A, B, X, Y```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer` and then `distinct` afterwards:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(state, education), names_to = "type", values_to = "value")
  group_by(sex) %>%
  distinct(value) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

In this case, `pivot_longer` simply puts state and education into one column called `value`.